# Updated PSDDLMODEL table for DDL Model Deaults, now getting buffer errors on page

Tags: peoplesoft

I was modifying the Model DDL Defaults in PeopleSoft and deleted and then re-added an index model default for Microsoft DB. I noticed when I re-added it that the Statement Type was blank and there was no option to select that it was an Index. I ended up performing an UPDATE SQL statement on the table `PSDDLMODEL` and I set the STATEMENT_TYPE equal to 2 (it was 0 previously).

Now when I load the page 'DDL Model Defaults' and select Microsoft as the platform I receive the message:

*No matching buffer found for level. (15,26)*

*When retrieving data for a page, a data value was retrieved for which there was no matching data value at a higher level scroll entry.  (For example, at scroll level 2, a value of ABC was read in and scroll level 1 contained this higher level field but did not have a row with a key value of ABC.)  This usually occurs because of an error in a database record or view; or because of improper deletion of values in a database.  Correct the page definition or contact your system administrator.*

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I was able to run the SQL UPDATE statement and set the STATMENT_TYPE back to 0 and refreshed the page online and it now loads properly. But I still have the issue of not having the STATEMENT_TYPE set to 'Index' and I have no option online to update it. I am puzzled how I am supposed to change it, if updating the table directly causes the buffer issues...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your DDL parameters are orphaned if you change the statement type in PSDDLMODEL.
You will have to perform an SQL UPDATE on STATEMENT_TYPE in PSDDLDEFPARMS as well.

```
UPDATE PSDDLDEFPARMS
SET STATEMENT_TYPE = '2'
WHERE STATEMENT_TYPE = '0'
  AND PLATFORMID = '7';
```

Your problem:

1. You add a new row in PSDDLMODEL (STATEMENT_TYPE will be 0)
2. You add parameters, they get inserted in PSDDLDEFPARMS with STATEMENT_TYPE 0
3. You update PSDDLMODEL setting STATEMENT_TYPE to 2 for 'Index'
4. Buffer mismatch.

The buffer loads PSDDLMODEL and PSDDLDEFPARMS, finds entries in PSDDLDEFPARMS for STATEMENT_TYPE 0, but can not match it to a parent row in PSDDLMODEL because you updated it. This is why setting STATEMENT_TYPE back to 0 in PSDDLMODEL 'fixes' the error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - There doesn't appear to be a way to change the Statement Type online to it's original value (2). Can it be done another way, or does this not matter?

Comment: @Nick The Statement Type field is display only and I don't see anything unlocking it. I assume the field has no real function and is just cosmetic for the standard peoplesoft entries. It just looks like an index with a translate value for 1-3 tbh.